# error #1146 in phpMyAdmin in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I did something dumb. I'd imported the create tables sql file twice. That's not the worst part however. I then proceeded to trying to drop the duplicate tables from the phpMyAdmin database. This is all that loads up when I click on phpMyAdmin now:

```
Error

SQL query:  Edit

SELECT `tables` 
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_recent` 
WHERE `username` = '[myusername]'

MySQL said: 

#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist
```

As in, just the above on an otherwise blank, white page.

*EDIT*
Everything returns to normal when I comment out the "Advanced Features" section in the config.inc.php file (the red exclamation signs are still beside everything, but I'm starting to wonder if that's just the default icon choice for phpMyAdmin 4.0.1). Once I uncomment them, the above returns. I've also noticed that the tables seems to be empty (maybe the reason for the exclamation signs?). Does that mean anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the tables inside `phpMyAdmin` database have two underscores `__` after the `pma` prefix. If that is the case, update the entries in you config.inc.php with an additional underscore.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you accidentally dropped one or more of your built-in databases/tables that keep phpmyadmin running.  The easiest solution is probably just to re-install XAMPP so you don't leave anything bugged by trying to do patchwork.

Just back up all of your created data.

I think specifically, you dropped the table that phpmyadmin stores your username in.  Now you have no usernames stored in it and therefore you can't log into phpmyadmin.

Comment: Even though I had it create the same tables twice? Oi...figured that was my only option.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could have two tables with identical names.  Something doesn't sound right to me.  I don't know exactly how it happened, but the error message is definitely telling you that the table that holds your phpmyadmin username is deleted.  That I do know.

Comment: It's time for me to run off to work.  If you're on Linux, you can type in the terminal:  mysql -u yourusername -p  and if it's set up properly you can still get into mysql and see your databases and tables the old fashioned way even with phpmyadmin broken;  maybe you can repair it.  Good luck.

Comment: What happened was that I had just updated phpMyAdmin. When I logged back in, I noticed all my databases had exclamation marks beside them, so (very stupidly, without checking) I thought I'd need to re-run create tables. All that did was create the same tables again without doing anything about the exclamation marks, so I (again, retardedly) started dropping tables. I think what I did was drop the tables that were there originally instead of the ones that were just imported. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I'm not too sure why.  Commenting out the advanced parts *does* work. Probably not the best way to go about it, but I'm sure that works for some people.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue as you but I found a way to solve it.

### from the create_tables.sql you got this:

### -- Table structure for table `pma_recent`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__recent` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tables` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='Recently accessed tables'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

---

the table name (pma__recent)contents two underscore characters by default, just remove one of them and recreate all the tables again by copy/paste the script into the SQL tab for phpmyadmin window. You should do the same thing for the others table name.